# changing sound/click on soft keyboard - android

Tags: android, audio, keyboard, click

I need some help with a project i'm doing. Hopefully someone can help me :)

I need to change the sound or click the keyboard makes whenever i'm typing in an editText. I need the sound/click to be whatever sound i may prefer (in wave-, mp3- or whatever format).

So, a couple of questions:

- Can i change this in the already implemented keyboard?
- Or should i make my own keyboard?
- if the latter is the case, how do i do that? Can i find the source code somewhere?

I have been looking at other questions regarding how to make your own keyboard. e.g. [How do I make my own keyboard for an app in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010714/how-do-i-make-my-own-keyboard-for-an-app-in-android)
And if i have to make my own keyboard i want to look like this. But how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

> > Can i change this in the already implemented keyboard?

You can't... it's already built and some manufactures provide their own keyboard implementations.

> > Or should i make my own keyboard?

Yes, you must.

> > If the latter is the case, how do i do that? Can i find the source code somewhere?

There are some open source projects of Keyboard implementations... for instance:

- https://github.com/g1011999/Gingerbread-Keyboard/
- http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/

There you can learn how to write your own keyboard, which is completely different from writing a conventional app.

My suggestion is to create a new fork of the Gingerbread-Keyboard (this supports Android 2.2 or higher only)... and then implement that specific change you want. For [one of my apps](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fullyinvolvedmedia.keyboard) I did so, and it's far easier than implementing the keyboard from scratch.