# creating own keypad on android

Tags: java, android, button, android-edittext, keypad

For my app I've made a keypad with its own set of buttons however I need to simulate the actual keypad with a few functions.

The buttons are drawn in a tablelayout in xml.

I need to simulate the next button to move the focus to the next edit text. The edit texts are handled as an array on the page.

I also need to simulate the typing of android's actual keyboard where it will add the key where the cursor is currently pointed at. Currently the keys will add/replace/remove from the back of the `EditText` string.

The keypad buttons are handled as an array.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        String tmp=texts[selectEdit].getText().toString();
        switch (n) {
            case 3: texts[selectEdit].setText(tmp.substring(0,tmp.length()-1));
                    break;//get cursor position and delete char
            case 7:{
                    Precision.performClick();
                    break;
                    }//spinner for selecting precision
            case 11:{
                    if(!tmp.contains("E"))
                        texts[selectEdit].setText(tmp+""+keybuttons[n].getText());
                    break;
                    }//check for E if dont have do default case
            case 15:{               
                    //calculator.num=n;
                    //startActivity(new Intent("com.easyPhys.start.calculator"));
                    break;
                    }//open Calculator
            case 16: break;//next field
            case 17: {
                      onBackPressed();
                      break;
                     }//simulate back button
            default:{
                    texts[selectEdit].setText(tmp+""+keybuttons[n].getText());
                    //get cursor start and end and get entire String
                    // replace selected String with button text
                    //insert back
                    break;
                    }
            }//end of switch
    }//end of try
```

Sorry for the improper sorting of code but I've tried to keep it as compact as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bellow link here you will have some information about custom keypad on android.

http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html

OR

[How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

Or

[How do I make my own keyboard for an app in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010714/how-do-i-make-my-own-keyboard-for-an-app-in-android)

Take a look, i think it will help you.