# android add buttons on top of softkeyboard

Tags: android, view, android-softkeyboard

I want to add some buttons on top of the soft keyboard (Enter and Cancel). Is there a nice way to do this or do I have to detect the keyboard being shown and add the buttons into my view?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the logic your trying to apply here.

if you add buttons above your keyboard then you lose some areas in your keyboard (for example you cant press on q w s a).

I think you should look into creating your own custom keyboard.

maybe this will help

[android app specific soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896939/android-app-specific-soft-keyboard)

Jason

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean on top of the keyboard. I meant vertically above.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this, and with good reason. If apps could modify an existing input method like this, they could trivially log all keystrokes on your device without you knowing. If you've ever installed a custom input method, you'll see a big warning that using it means trusting it not to log your keystrokes, and the functionality you're after would totally circumvent that protection.

Comment: I only want to modify the keyboard for my application where I can easily listen for keystrokes anyway.

Comment: Ah okay. In any case, I'm not sure that the functionality exists at all. It's a bit of a cheesy hack, but would adding the two buttons you want to the bottom of a RelativeLayout not do the trick? They'd at least be in the same area, even though not part of the keyboard itself.