# Can we create virtual keyboard for a specific app?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, virtual-keyboard

Is it possible to create a virtual keyboard for a specific application....I have gone through this example [virtual keyboard](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html) but it is replacing the system keyboard not for a specific application....How can i achieve virtual keyboard for a specific application....please suggest any valuable posts or links

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890071/view-specific-ime

Comment: http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for-android-devices/ check it.

Comment: I didnt find correct solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link and you'll get your answer

[android app specific soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896939/android-app-specific-soft-keyboard)