# Show suggestions of AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Is it possible to have the AutoCompleteTextView show the suggestions above the keyboard just like when using the default dictionary? (If yes, how:))

Or can I use my own database to show suggestion when using EditText?

Hope you understand what I mean:)

Thank you

Bastaixen

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The suggestions shown above the keyboard are actually part of the IME, so completely unrelated to your application / activity.

The only way to do this would be for you to build-in your own IME and then you can customize what suggestions would be there. You can base it on [latinIME](http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_inputmethods_latinime/trees/ab17fca519fa27af01d29a38c553e250c9e92a9e/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin), but there are still a couple of things you would need to figure out:

- You would need to figure out how to tell Android to use your custom IME in your app. Or, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5890380/347565) say, just build in the keyboard in your app.
- if your user is using a different keyboard (for different language, or swype or something like that), they would probably not like it much...