# Alternate View for Android Keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard, soft-keyboard

So I'm working on developing an alternate android keyboard that instead of showing the traditional soft keyboard displays a set of cards in a recyclerview. Or basically a set of predetermined sayings that the user can scroll through to pick which message to send. I've gone through countless tutorials and have developed the Softkeyboard. How exactly do I go about making this alternate view for the keyboard happen though. Is there a way to show a custom view instead of the keyboard view. If anyone could help show me how this is done it would be much appreciated thanks for the help.

Comment: follow this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890071/view-specific-ime