# programmatically enable and set inputmethod

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am developing Bluetooth keyboard driver for android. I want to enable my keyboard input method automatically and set it,  by just click of toggle button. By enabling I mean [image]

[image]

Now I want to do this programmatically by just one click of toggle button , i want to bypass these steps for the user and provide them a toggle button which is doing these steps.

```
InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) BluezIMESettings.this.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
m.setInputMethod(token, id);
```

Now where i can get this token and ID ? , i searched in API description i get this

**token**  Supplies the identifying token given to an input method when it was started, which allows it to perform this operation on itself.

**id**  The unique identifier for the new input method to be switched to.

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set the Input Method programmatically, you have to navigate to the settings so the users can change the settings. Android secured this option so no bloatware takes over the device.

Same story as enabling GPS programmatically, it is not possible!

Also se [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901097/change-input-method-of-android-device-programatically-android).

Comment: Absolutely correct. Input methods have many security and privacy implications for users; apps are not permitted to change these settings silently.

Answer (score 2):

You CAN set the input method programmatically, but you have to sign your app with a platform key to be able to write secure settings (android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS), which limits your possibilities to your own ports of Android.

The simple answer -- "it is not possible... " -- is in fact incorrect, if you sign your app with a platform key.

Comment: Unfortunately, signing with the platform key is not a standard way of operating for developers who want to build and release apps for Google Play, so this is likely unhelpful to the OP. This question seems interesting though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247818/android-after-building-platform-source-how-to-sign-arbitrary-apk-with-platform