# How to enable localization support in Apportable UIKit?

Tags: internationalization, apportable

Currently, I am trying Apportable starter kit. I know that it has limited UIKit support, but it seems lacking internationalization/localization feature.

Here are my questions.

1. How to display non-roman Unicode letters? (east asian script)
2. How to input non-Enbglish characters with system keyboard? (east asian IME) In my device, keyboards are enabled and displayed, but when I input some characters with the keyboard, it just input English characters instead of expected IME compositions. (I am not trying to change user settings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apportable SDK currently has an issue with NSString non-ASCII constant initializers.

You may be running into a platform bug initializing NSString's with constants.

A workaround would be something like :

```
#ifdef APPORTABLE
    imageCopyright = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Image © C"];
#else
    imageCopyright = @"Image © C";
#endif
```

My understanding is that the Android keyboard is not programmatically configurable. It is controlled by user settings. See [Change Input method of android device programatically android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901097/change-input-method-of-android-device-programatically-android)

Comment: Thanks for answer. This solved issue #1. And for #2, I had mistake on wording. I updated the wording in question.

Comment: #2 sounds like a bug. Can you provide more details about the specific use case that fails? Also, it might be clearer to create a different question.

Comment: Sure. I will post another question with some sample.

Comment: I posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228792/how-to-enable-international-keyboard-support-in-apportable