# Drawing unicode characters with apportable?

Tags: android, unicode, apportable

I am trying (and failing) to display unicode characters using `NSString.drawAtPoint` within Apportable.

Trying to display something like `@"TEST 太"` will display just `T`.  Other words might show only the Latin characters and not the foreign Unicode.

Any ideas on how to get this working correctly in Apportable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"TEST 太"];
```

As for me I convert all my strings in projects from this kind `NSString *str = @"Strings"` to this one `NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Strings"];`. And it's correctly works in both iOS & Apportable versions of project. No need to make `#ifdef ANDROID ...` blocks like that [How to enable localization support in Apportable UIKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219430/how-to-enable-localization-support-in-apportable-uikit)

Comment: I tried this and it shows TEST, but the other characters are still not showing up.

Comment: Given that you have already done the 
    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"TEST 太"];
version of your string, you may be running into a font issue.  Are you trying to use a custom font for this string, or are you using the default, which should be Roboto?

Comment: Using [UIFont systemFontOfSize: fontSize], the Japanese character is showing up now, but the Emoji still doesn't show up.  Will I need to add an Emoji font to the app to get it to show correctly?

Comment: I was able to get the Emoji to display by adding the OpenSansEmoji ttf font to the project, and adding "OpenSansEmoji.ttf" to "Fonts provided by application" in the Info.plist.  Unfortunately, I seem to lose the ability to mix emoji and bold non-emoji, but it seems to be a workable solution for now.