# How to make my edit text use Arabic keyboard programmatically?

Tags: android

Right now it's showing English when click on the edit text. How can I change the keyboard to Arabic?
I tried installing Arabic keyboard from Google Play, but it is not working in my app.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901097/change-input-method-of-android-device-programatically-android

Comment: Is there any way to create a custom keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set a keyboard for an EditText. The keyboard (or IME) can only be set manually by the user. All you can do is open the dialog from where the user can choose the keyboard. Even for that, the keyboard needs to be enabled in the Language and Input settings

```
private void showInputMethodPicker() {
        InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
        if (imeManager != null) {
            imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_possible_im_picker, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there any way to create a custom keyboard in Arabic?

Comment: Even if you create a custom keyboard, you won't be able to select it automatically. To make a keyboard, there are tutorials on the Android developers website.