# How to develop a custom Soft Keyboard for Android application?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I've got an Math related application I've made that I really would like to make a custom soft keyboard for. It would have attributes like a numpad and special characters like pi and square root symbols built in. I would want it to replace to default keyboard just for that application, and only open the keyboard that I develop for this app. My question is how do I do that? Do I make a "keyboard" out of table layouts and a bunch of buttons that opens when I click on the text field, or do I make use of the keyboard layout?

Comment: The Wolfram:Alpha app does this.

Answer (score 3):

You should not create a table layout and a bunch of buttons, it is an unfamiliar user interface and creates a bad user experience. See this answer about how to create a custom soft keyboard that is identical to the platform soft keyboard but contains the keys you need: [android app specific soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896939/android-app-specific-soft-keyboard/8747979#8747979)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a RelativeLayout, with rows of buttons like a keyboard at the bottom of the screen(using Linear layouts), or if you need to have a system wide keyboard, I'd look at [Hackerskeyboard](https://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/source/checkout) source for an example.

Comment: Ok, I've got the layout that I want made, but my textfields are at the bottom of the screen and are hidden when I pull up the layout.