# How to completely disable soft keyboard for all input in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-webview, android-websettings

I am using phonegap to develop a web app for Android, and since I will have my own keypad in HTML, I need to disable android's system keyboard, preventing the it from showing up when the user clicks on any text input field. I don't want to use readonly input field or `onblur()` since I would like to have the cursor in the text filed so user can move the cursor position while they're entering inputs.

So I want to completely disable Android's keyboard on default, I tried adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` to `manifest.xml` but this does not work.

I also try use a javascript interface from [here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/27915465/How%20to%20show%20and%20hide%20soft%20keyboard%20in%20Android), but there was a javascript-java bridge crash issue on Android 2.3.x.([link to issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987)). So I still don't have a good solution now. Please help.

Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you configured the `WebView`'s `WebViewClient` and `WebChromeClient`?  I worked on a project that used jQuery Mobile and we had to configure both of those for things to work properly.  You may have to intercept a JS event and tie that into the Java logic in the native code.  I'll look into this and keep you updated.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I think phonegap already configured both webviewclient and webchromeclient. I will look more into it. thanks

Comment: Okay, look into my suggestions below.  It doesn't look like there's a pretty way to do this, but then again doing anything prettily in Android is near impossible in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you've got a few options!  You can try to disable the keyboard completely using:

- `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`

  - If you choose this way, be sure to return the settings to normal if that's not done automatically.  I haven't used this before and couldn't tell you how it behaves, but keep that in mind!  You don't want a user to reply to a text they receive while using your app only to have their keyboard disabled :)

- You could use something similar to the following link.  I haven't dug through it very thoroughly (tl;dr) but he creates a custom view that extends from `android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView` and uses that instead.

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1947370/1183256

- Lastly (I'm not sure how much this would differentiate from the first one) you could create your own IME.

  - [How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android/3480756#3480756)
  - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html