# Custom Dictionary (not keyboard) for Android apps

Tags: android, keyboard

Is there a way to load an app specific custom dictionary for android keyboard auto-complete to show to the users? My app uses a few hundred words only and any input other than these words is going to be useless.

I want to just load the word list used in my app and override the default android (or swype/swiftkey dictionaries if they are installed), without the hassle of implementing a full blown keyboard.

I have seen a couple of similar questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896939/android-app-specific-soft-keyboard), but nothing that answers my question. [Android IME](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) again requires you to write a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think that make SQLite database in your application in your android application and load this data in the autocomplete and when the user entered the text then check that whether the word he entered lies in that database or not. If yes, then keep this in that textbox otherwise make text of that textbox empty i.e "". Hope that this will work for you....