# Capturing KeyPress Events in Android WebView

Tags: android

Currently, my application have a webView that loads certain forms/websites etc.

Now I want to capture the KeyPressEvents within this webView. Below is the code I am using:

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent KEvent) 
    {
        int keyaction = KEvent.getAction();

        if(keyaction == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            int keycode = KEvent.getKeyCode();
            int keyunicode = KEvent.getUnicodeChar(KEvent.getMetaState() );
            char character = (char) keyunicode;

            Toast.makeText(this,"DEBUG MESSAGE KEY=" + character + " KEYCODE=" +  keycode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(KEvent);
    }
```

Using the above code, I could only capture for backspace and numbers. Alphabets and special characters are not reflected.

Is it suppose to be like that? Or I must create my own app specific keyboard to capture the keypress events ([android app specific soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896939/android-app-specific-soft-keyboard/8747979#8747979))?

Answer (score 3):

Just put this code in your webview and everything will work as a charm.

```
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
   return new BaseInputConnection(this, false); 
}
```

Comment: Here is a more complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45312554/1623342

Answer (score 0):

OnKeyListener can be used for capturing key events on webView.

```
    mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // You can get any keyCode or KeyEvent here
            return false;
        }
    });
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html