# Android WebView HTML input keypress doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, java, android, input, webview

On some devices (mostly Samsung, but others too) and combinations of: Android version, WebView version (even with the evergreen WebView in Android 7) and keyboard, there are a number of issues:

- `keypress` isn't fired
- `keydown` and `keyup` always contain `keyCode=229`
- `keypress` and `input` are fired but don't contain the key
- `textInput` isn't fired
- `maxlength` attribute isn't honored on `input[type=text]` while the user types (more than `maxlength` chars are allowed and the input is validated only when the form is submitted)

Is there a way to fix these issues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that if you extend `WebView` and override `onCreateInputConnection`, all of those issues are fixed:

```
public class WebViewExtended extends WebView {
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        // This line fixes some issues but introduces others, YMMV.
        // super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);

        return new BaseInputConnection(this, false);
    }
}
```

Before overriding `onCreateInputConnection`:

[image: before]

After overriding `onCreateInputConnection` (`g` was pressed):

[image: after]

Comment: Seriously: _thank you_ just about a million times . What did you mean by "fixes some issues but introduces others, YMMV."?

Comment: @VH-NZZ glad this helped you. Initially, without the `super` call, we found that sometimes the user would open a numeric keyboard in another app, and when returning to our app, only that same numeric keyboard would be opened for *any* field, even if for text fields. The `super` call fixed that for us. But it introduced a problem in some specific devices (can't recall which) where typing wouldn't work: the user would hit the keyboard and nothing happened. That's why your mileage may vary and you should test if this solution works for your specific scenario.

Comment: Cheers for this explanation mate. This is a bit of a pain to manage but luckily the user base I'm target is around 20 and all use the same hardware.

Comment: Tried this and it wasn't working initially. Until I found this: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/managing-keyboard-on-webview-d2e89109d106 Point 4: You'll have to add `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`to your mark-up to make it work. At least at Android API Level 26 and above.

Comment: This would seemingly prevent IME from working - at least that's the result that I see when I try this.