# show keyboard with text and numbers for user id in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I am making an Android app where I need the user to fill a form. In this form there is a field where the user has to put her/his ID (for example passport) and I would like to know if it is possible to show a keyboard with numbers and text at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this thread can help you out.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/22563088/6577892

try to set: android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"

Comment: share your love if it helped you out. :)

Comment: Thank you @SubhanAli that's what i was looking for. I only have to add android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" to my EditText.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show the softkeyboard with only alphanumeric keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563088/show-the-softkeyboard-with-only-alphanumeric-keys)

Comment: You are right @kuzdu. That was i wanted to know but already it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set runtime the keyboard's type, use this example:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.its_your_EditText); 
editText.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD); //TYPE_CLASS_TEXT is the default
```

And use this example if you want to show the keyboard immediately:

```
if (editText.requestFocus()) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```