# Android - How to make the keyboard impossible to dismiss?

Tags: android, keyboard, dismiss

I've searched everywhere but I haven't found anything so far. I have a Fragment in which I force the display of the Keyboard (Numeric keypad to be more precise). However I'd like to know if there was a way to make this keyboard IMPOSSIBLE to dismiss (via the back button or whatsoever). I tried to deactivate the back button but no success.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Why would the user want this?

Comment: It is a requirement I am asked to implement so the question here isn't really about the user experience.

Comment: Perhaps you want a app specific custom keyboard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896939/android-app-specific-soft-keyboard as it would be a view and you can customize any 'back' behavior.